# what is the difference for python between lambda and regular function?

Tags: python, lambda

I'm curious about the difference between `lambda` function and a regular function (defined with `def`) - in the python level. (I know what is the difference for programmers and when to use each one.)

```
>>> def a():
    return 1

>>> b = lambda: 1
>>> a
<function a at 0x0000000004036F98>
>>> b
<function <lambda> at 0x0000000004031588>
```

As we can see - python **knows** that `b` is a `lambda` function and `a` is a regular function. why is that? what is the difference between them **to python**?

Comment: Python supports the creation of anonymous functions (i.e. functions that are not bound to a name) at runtime, using a construct called "lambda". You can check it in http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk. It means it's not giving you the name of function.

Comment: @SuryawanshiManoj What about this question leads you to believe that OP is unaware of that?

Comment: @Marcin: As Simeon Visser Shown the example below in answer, you can understand that OP is unaware of the name of function

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They are the same type so they are treated the same way:

```
>>> type(a)
<type 'function'>
>>> type(b)
<type 'function'>
```

Python also knows that `b` was defined as a lambda function and it sets that as function name:

```
>>> a.func_name
'a'
>>> b.func_name
'<lambda>'
```

In other words, it influences the name that the function will get but as far as Python is concerned, both are functions which means they can be mostly used in the same way. See mgilson's comment below for an important difference between functions and lambda functions regarding pickling.

Comment: lambda functions can't be pickled because they have no (unique) name associated with them.  (Therefore, they can't be used with `multiprocessing` for example -- which has bit me with a `PicklingError` on more than one occasion )

Comment: Also, it might be worth pointing out that `lambda` is an expression whereas `def` is a statement.  Since `lambda` is an expression, it can only contain other expressions (no statements are allowed) -- Although this is more of an issue at the programmer's level as opposed to "Why does python keep track of the difference"

Comment: lambdas can also be used as expressions, where traditional functions cannot; but I think you knew this already.

Comment: Considering that internally `a` and `b` are of the same type, i.e. both are `function`s, I assume that there is no performance advantage of one over the other?

Answer (score 15):

The only difference is that (a) the body of a lambda can consist of only a single expression, the result of which is returned from the function created and (b) a `lambda` expression is an expression which evaluates to a function object, while a `def` statement has no value, and creates a function object and binds it to a name.

In all other material respects they result in identical objects - the same scope and capture rules apply. (Immaterial differences are that `lambda`-created functions have a default `func_name` of `"<lambda>"`. This may affect operation in esoteric cases - e.g. attempts to pickle functions.).

Answer (score 3):

Both `lambda` and `def` create the same kind of function – they have the same kind of metadata and capabilities. Their technical difference is *syntactical*:

- A `lambda` is an *expression* producing a function.
- A `def` is a *statement* producing a function.

This is everything that dictates how they can be *used*. Other apparent differences simply come from the information `lambda`/`def` can capture.

```py
>>> def def_func(): pass
>>> lambda_func = lambda: None
>>> type(def_func) == type(lambda_func)
True
```

---

###### Usage: Expression vs. Statement

A `lambda` is more flexible as expressions can be *part of* more language constructs.

```py
#                v--------------v arguments must be expressions
sort(values, key=lambda x: abs(x))
```

In contrast, a `def` is more powerful as it can *consist of* more language constructs.

```py
def encode(num, base):
    while num:   # statements must be inside statements
        num, bit = divmod(num, base)
        yield bit
```

These differences derive directly from one being an expression and the other being a statement. Python has no special rules to decide where a `lambda`/`def` may be used.

---

###### Where the wild `<lambda>`s grow

The primary reason to assume `lambda` and `def` correspond to different kinds of function is *metadata*: `lambda` is often referred to as an "anonymous function" and miraculously it always produces a `function <lambda>`. Other quirks include "lambda functions can't be pickled", and recently typing also does "not work" for `lambda`.

That is because compared to `def` syntax, the `lambda` syntax has no way of specifying name, type annotations and similar. As such, Python simply fills in sane *defaults* for either: the name becomes `<lambda>` and annotations are left empty.

```py
>>> identity = lambda a: a
>>> identity.__qualname__
'<lambda>'
>>> identity.__annotations__
{}
```

Since `<lambda>` is not a valid identifier, everything using this metadata to find the function – most prominently `pickle` – fails.

However, that does not make the function an "anonymous function" type. The metadata can be patched up to insert what `def` would provide:

```py
>>> identity.__qualname__ = identity.__name__ = 'identity'
>>> identity
<function __main__.identity(a)>
```

Of course at that one point one can just use `def`…

Answer (score 1):

First consider the diff b/w the two.

**Lambda functions:** are operator can have any number of arguments, but it can have only one expression. It cannot contain any statements and it returns a function object which can be assigned to any variable. They can be used in the block they were created.

**def functions:** Functions help break our program into smaller and modular chunks. As our program grows larger and larger, functions make it more organised and manageable. They can be called and used anywhere we want.

Here you can get more clear difference by following example.

## Defining a function

```
    def add(a,b):
      return a+b
    print(add(4,5))
```

## Defining a lambda

```
    add = lambda x, y : x + y 
    print(add(4,5))
```

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh, but my question was what is the difference for *python*, not how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`lambda` creates an anonymous function. This idea has been taken from functional programming languages. In this way you can create and pass the function to other functions like `map` and `filter`. (look [here](http://docs.python.org/release/1.4/tut/node80.html))
You can pass normal functions to these functions too, but since mostly they are simple and they are not used anywhere else, it's inconvenient to go through the whole process of definfing a new function.

As an example take a look at this:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print map( lambda x : x*2 + 1, a )
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lambda is an inline function where we can do any functionality without a function name.
It is helpful when we use it as an argument to a higher-order function. 
Eg: A function that takes in other functions as arguments.

Example of Function definition:

```
>>> def func(a, b):
    return a * b

>>> func(2,3)
6
>>> type(func)
<class 'function'>
>>> func
<function func at 0x034B6E88>
```

Example of Lambda expression:

```
>>> multiply = lambda a, b: a * b
>>> multiply(2, 3)
6
>>> type(multiply)
<class 'function'>
>>> multiply
<function <lambda> at 0x034B6ED0>
```

Both returns same output value. Only object returned are different. "func" name for Function and  for Lambda.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but pay attention to the fact that I know what is the difference for programmers and when to use each one (as i said in the question).