# Difference between 'lambda' and 'def' statement?

Tags: python

I am learning Python since one year, I don't found 'lambda' useful. 'lambda' is much similar to 'def' statement. I need an example where I must need to use 'lambda' statement and I can't use 'def' here at all.

Comment: `lambda` is simply for convenience.  It is never necessary.

Comment: you must use the lambda function if you are only allowed to use one line to write the function ...

Comment: `a.sort(lambda x: x.foo)` vs. `def callback(x): return x.foo; a.sort(callback)` – use it when it makes sense, that's all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12264881/524743

Comment: lambda is not a statement, it's an expression. That's why you can use it in expression contexts.

Comment: It's like the different between `x + y` and `z = x + y`. The first calculates a value, the second calculates the value and gives it a name.

Comment: As the very first comment says: **it is never _necessary_.** And I posted an example of where a `lambda` makes more sense because it is much more concise. There's nothing more to it than that. It's simply *more concise* when you don't need a full `def`.