# How can I create a list of R=10000 booleans called inside in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, boolean

```
import random, math

random.seed(1)

def in_circle(x, origin = [0]*2):
    """
        This function determines if a two-dimensional point
        falls within the unit circle.
    """
    if len(x) != 2:
        return "x is not two-dimensional!"
    elif distance(x, origin) < 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(in_circle((1,1)))
```

Next, I want to determine whether each point in x falls within the unit circle centered at (0,0) using the function "in_circle". How do I do it?
My level of programming - Beginner

Comment: What does your `distance(x, origin)` function look like?

Comment: Distance function is the square root of the sum of squared differences along each dimension of x and y. 
`distance = math.sqrt((y[0] - x[0])**2 + (y[1] - x[1])**2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your `distance` function looks like but assuming your `x` variable passed to the function has 10000 points, this is a way you can compute your boolean array. While calling the function `in_circle`, you can pass your array/list of all 10000 points and replace `[(1,1), (1,2), (2,2)])` in `in_circle([(1,1), (1,2), (2,2)])` by your array/list containing points. Let me know if it doesn't work.

In this solution, you will call the function `in_circle` once by passing all the 10000 points together and then the `for` loop will compute the distances inside the function. In my opinion, it is better than putting the `for` loop outside and calling the function 10000 times for each point one by one.

```
import random, math

random.seed(1)

def in_circle(x, origin = [0]*2):
    bool_array = []
    for point in x: # assuming x contains 10000 points
        if len(x) != 2:
            print ("x is not two-dimensional!")
            continue
        elif distance(x, origin) < 1:
            bool_array.append(True) 
        else:
            bool_array.append(False) 
    return bool_array

bool_array = in_circle([(1,1), (1,2), (2,2)])
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, distance function is the square root of the sum of squared differences along each dimension of x and y. distance = math.sqrt((y[0] - x[0])**2 + (y[1] - x[1])**2)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Just put your 1000 points or any amount of coordinates in a list li below and run your function over them using a loop and you will get your booleans in a list X. Like:

```
 x=[] #declare an empty list where boolean value needs to be stored
li=[(1,1),(0,0),(-1,1)]

for i in range(0,len(li)):
    x1=in_circle(li[i])
    x.append(x1)
```

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer, if it was of any help. Thanks :)

Comment: Where exactly are you storing booleans in a list here? Plz read the question title. Perhaps you can modify your code to OP's need

Comment: @Bazingaa Thanks for the suggestion. Edited the answer based on your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Not correct yet. Try to find the error in 4th and 5th lines of your solution before I point them out

Comment: @Bazingaa Thanks Again and sorry for the late reply :)

Comment: You could have stuck to `for i in li:` and used `x1=in_circle(i)` since you are not using an index anywhere. So using `range` is unnecessary here

Answer (score 0):

as I understand, you have the list of tuples like this

```
l = [(x1, y1),
     (x2, y2),
     ...
     (x10000, y10000)]
```

what you need in that case is to iterate over it
but first, create a list that will contain booleans

```
bools = []
for xy in l: # xy is tuple
    bools.append(in_circle(xy))
```

that was begginer level, but there's even fancier way of doing it:

```
bools = [in_circle(xy) for xy in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

If lever of programming beginner, you will find useful to also look at these concepts, they ll be handy in your programmer future:

`map`, `lambda` and `generators`.

1. You could define simple functions using lambda functions.

As:

```
in_circle = lambda (x, y): True if Math.sqrt( Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2) ) < 1 else False
# assuming circle has center 0, 0  and radius 1
```

2.
and then map the function to a list of points:

```
map( in_circle, your_list)
```

Note that in lambda the syntax (x, y) is because you are passing a tuple as one argument, and your list is formed like:

```
your_list = [(0,1),(0, 0.5), (0.3, 0.4) ...]
```

3.
Instead of list, you can also use a generator, a structure very handy in iterations if you don't need to use again your list.

syntax is similar (note the brakets ! ( VS [ )

```
your_point = [ (random.random(), random.random()) for i in range(n)  ] 
# list comprehension

your_point = (  (random.random(), random.random()) for i in range(n)  )
# generator
```

4.
So you could generate a list of N booleans like:

```
n = 10000
your_point = ( (random.random(), random.random()) for i in range(n) )
bool_list = map( in_circle, your_list)
```

---

For your curiosity in difference between lamdba and regular functions, see also:
[what is the difference for python between lambda and regular function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264834/what-is-the-difference-for-python-between-lambda-and-regular-function)

For your interest in generators VS lists comprehension:
[Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

Comment: How come that this answer was chosen as correct, and now I got notification from Stackoverflow with -15 points in my reputation because OP change his mind?? Aside that answer is correct, I took effort to explain other key concepts in python, because OP said "My level of programming - Beginner".  Bah.. oh well, it won't be a drama - I ve learnt many things thanks to SO community, and wanted to return the favour.