# Sorting list based on frequency if letters - Huffman Algorithm

Tags: python

I don't know how to order a list of letters and their frequencies in ascending order i.e `{'z':1, 'g':3, 'a':5, and so on}`

I'm trying to recreate the Huffman Algorithm, a lossless compression algorithm, in Python. `txt` is a string of text, that was been split up so each letter, including spaces, is an individual index. I have tried using `Counter(txt)`, which finds how many times each letter appears in `txt` and creates a dictionary. But this orders the dictionary from highest frequency to lowest frequency, and I need it to be vice-versa, so that it follows the steps of Huffman Algorithm. I then tried adding

```
for key, value in sorted(freq.iteritems(), key=lambda(k,v): (v,k)):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, value))
```

However this creates a syntax error, and I dont know if this is the best way to do it.

Here is my code:

```
from collections import Counter
def huffman(file):
    txt = list(map(lambda c2: c2, file)) # Places each individual char into array.
    freq=Counter(txt) #Counts numb of times a letter appears.
    print(freq)
    for key, value in sorted(freq.iteritems(), key=lambda(k,v): (v,k)):
        print("%s: %s" % (key, value))
```

I just need the `freq` dictionary to be order from least common to most common so that it follows the steps of Huffman's algorithm. So instead of `{'a':5, 'g':3, 'z':1}` it is `{'z':1, 'g':3, 'a':5}`

Comment: python dictionaries do not maintain an internal 'order'. The result you are getting is only a coincidence, in truth it is not ordered at all. You can create an `OrderedDict` from `collections` which will remember the order that items are inserted into the dict. So you can make sure to add them in the order youc are about.

Comment: @WoodyPride The ordering of dicts are dependant on the Python version used. Since Python 3.7 they are ordered by insertion order as per the documentation

Comment: Good to know! I had not realized that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On python version 3.6 or below, use this:

`from collections import OrderedDict
freq = OrderedDict(sorted(freq.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))`

Beginning from python version 3.7, you can use this:
`freq = dict(sorted(freq.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))`

Dictonary beginning from version 3.7 and above dictonary is ordered by default.
The fist element of each tuple is the alphabet and the second element is it's frequency. So, in the sorted function, we use the frequency of each element as the key to sort the elements in increasing order.

Comment: Hm. Wouldn't this turn it into a list like : `[('z', 1), ('g', 3), ('a', 5)]`? The OP wants a dictionary I believe.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's still not right :) Dict will just convert it into a regular dictionary without order. You almost have it though!

Comment: I think, the order of the elements inside the list, should be maintained..
OrderedDict might help.

Comment: @LeKhan9 That ordering depends on the Python version used, Python3.7 keeps insertion order

Comment: Note that ordering by insertion is implemented in CPython for 3.6 but only guaranteed since Python 3.7. That means that other implementations of Python will not support it before version 3.7. Please add this to your answer

Comment: Thank you @taurus05! I have stuck on this for hours trying to figure it out! Just a quick question though, what does the `lambda x: x[1]` part do? Just simply curious.

Comment: If you know inline functions in c++, it is somewhat analogus to it. `lambdas` are anonymous functions, which are used to perform a set of tasks (which the fuctions can also accomplish), but they more pythonic. You can refer to this answer for more info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264834/what-is-the-difference-for-python-between-lambda-and-regular-function

Answer (score 0):

If you really want an ordered dictionary back you have to jump through a couple of hoops :)

You'd want to sort that dictionary first to obtain a flat list:

```
import operator
a = {'a':5, 'g':3, 'z':1}
sorted_list = sorted(a.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

and then, you'd pass that to an OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted_list)
```

ordered_dict:

```
OrderedDict([('z', 1), ('g', 3), ('a', 5)])
```

then, you can index as such:

```
ordered_dict['z']
```

output:

```
1
```

Comment: Since Python3.7 dictionaries preserve insertion order

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @LeKhan9! I ended up using the answer above, but I did try yours and it produced the same results. Thank you again!