Understanding the difference between lambda and function definition
Tried -
sorted_dict= sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])```
```this works but replacing lambda with a function does not work.```
```python
def func(a):
    return a[1]
sorted_dict= sorted(a.items(), key=func(x))```

it throws x is undefined and yes that makes sense but how does it work for lambda? hoping to get an explanation on why lambda works and replacing the same with the function method does not work.
I thought lambda and function definitions could be used interchangeably. any explanation on how I could make a sorted dictionary based on values by using a function instead of lambda would help.```

key=func - you need to pass the function, not call it.

note, if you did func = lambda x: x[1] on a prior line, then tried sorted(a.items(), key=func(x)) it would fail in the exact same way. Function objects created by lambda expressions are the same type of object as a function object created by function definition statements. Both of those are language constructs that result in function objects being created

For more interesting answers than someone else's usage error this question has answers that dig into the suprisingly few differences between Lambdas and defined functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264834/what-is-the-difference-for-python-between-lambda-and-regular-function

sorted_dict = sorted(a.items(), key=func)

You don't need to mention any x when supplying a function itself
